# Can ArcGIS Python API automate functionality provided in Web AppBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-python-api

I was feeling adventurous the other day and I decided to dive into ArcGIS Pro and the new ArcGIS Python API.  I watched some training videos and since I've been working with ArcGIS Online a lot, I thought it would be a good idea to learn the new API.  The admin functionality seems like it's worth the effort to learn but they state it's very helpful for automating the production of apps.  I was able to automate the basic web map production but nowadays everybody is using the Web AppBuilder or they're doing all the coding through the new Server software.  It hardly seems worth the effort of automating the map production if you still have to configure the app with all the widgets.

I guess what I'm asking is can you automate workflows needed to build the sort of apps you get using the Online Web AppBuilder?